# Container inside Row and Row inside Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-container

In a flutter app, what is the difference between a Container inside a Row and a Row inside Container?
In flutter in  each time I want to make an app, I took minutes to ask my self
which one should I choose?

Comment: do you have any background in coding?

Answer (score 0):

In flutter `Row` and `Column` provide a way to use the `Flex` layout system aka `FlexBox`.

In short `Flex` is a one-dimensional layout system, where in the children can be aligned on the main-axis or cross-axis, the main axis can be defined as horizontal or vertical.

A `Container` in `Flutter` is a general-purpose widget that gives you access to a range of properties like padding, decoration, size etc. A [full-list is available at the API Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)

To answer your question,

A `Container` in a `Row` is like we said above, a child of a `Flex`, which means it will respect the properties of alignment set by the parent (MainAxisAlignment/CrossAxisAlignment )

A `Row` in a `Container`, is the opposite of that which means that, the `Row` or `Column` will respect properties set on the `Container` that is for example the `Decoration` or `Size` properties amongst others.